# Struts 1.x ActionForm Action Class

Tags: java, javabeans, struts-1, struts-action, actionform

I've got a simple html page with four buttons. I know how to map the buttons so that the Action Class gets the value of whatever is selected and call a method based on each button in the Action Class.  However, what should I do with the Action Form? Can I just leave it blank? It seems that struts requires you to map a bean, yet I'm not really sure what to put in the Action Form, since all that I'm trying to do is call methods in the Action Class.

Comment: Are you looking for  stackoverflow.com/questions/11986599/struts-using-multiple-submit-buttons-for-one-form-how-to-know-which-was-clic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struts is what we call nowadays as "action-based" framework. Nowadays most frameworks are what we call "event-based" framework.

It was built to make your life easier when you need to fill huge html forms and then send it to the server.

It was not intended to make your life easier when pressing a button to execute some code on the server and then return with that specific small result.

The main idea of struts was that, big things and change the entire view.

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-hello-world-example/) example (and mabye [those ones](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2EE/Exercise1BuildingyourfirstStrutsApplication.htm), takes forever to download) how easier struts made the form-processing easier. see "5. Action (Controller)" of [first link](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-hello-world-example/).

If not clear, in the time, when there were just servlets, you needed something like [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/handling-html-form-data-with-java-servlet) to parse a form.

**TL;DR;** In the end the ActionForm is there just to help you with your html forms that otherwise you would need to parse by hand instead to receive them as well-formed java beans.

Comment: Right. I understand what you are saying. I'm still learning though. As a beginner, I'm trying to understand what to do with button clicks. In this particular example my buttons are part of a form, but there are no text fields or anything to fill out - only buttons. Since there are no text fields, I'm not sure what to do with those button presses.The form that encloses the buttons takes you to a second jsp, and I was trying to see if i could get DispatchAction to work.

Comment: No problem, if you don't have a form then you don't need to bother about the ActionForm at all. Struts offer them and are quite centered on it, but you can go ahead without it for now.

It's not my business, but may i ask you why to start to learning java web with struts?

IMO start directly with servlets (the 3.0 spec at least) can offer a better understanding of how the things came to what we have now in the JEE scenario.

Comment: try tomcat 8, downloading the .tar.gz version it comes with all docs and examples, and supports servlet specification ver. 3.1, which is good since you can use annotations instead xml to configure servlet mappings: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

Answer (score 2):

**Purpose of ActionForm** is to map your fields in your *html forms* to a corresposnding bean which can be mapped in your strus-config.xml inside the form-bean tag.

**Can I just leave it blank?** yes the ActionForm is not a required field in <action> tag.